# Como retirar itens automáticos de uma activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

No Android Studio, na hora de criar uma activity, a IDE já coloca alguns itens dentro dela, como aquele círculo com um envelope dentro(imagem). Como eu retiro isso após criada a activity?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já fez várias perguntas sobre como eliminar "coisas" que o *Android Studio* gera quando cria um novo projecto, se não as quer utilizar escolha a opção ***Empty Activity*** ao criá-lo.

Comment: Sim, mas já tem muita coisa criada. Queria ver como retiro estas coisas para não ter retrabalho.

Comment: Na hora de escolher o tipo de activity escolha uma activity vazia, se não me engano seria a empty activity, ela vai criar apenas com o onCreate e a inicialização do layout. Ou você pode apagar o método que nesse caso acho que é o floattingbutton. Mas o primeiro modo acho melhor.

Comment: É o floatingbutton sim, Vinicius. dentro do **activity_main.xml**. Obrigada!

Comment: Não esqueça de marcar a resposta se te ajudou.

Comment: Vinicius, vc enviou um um comentário, não uma resposta para a pergunta. Envie a resposta que eu consigo votar aqui ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você cria uma nova activity o Android Studio tenta facilitar seu trabalho deixando varias coisa criadas. Como o caso da Toolbar e do FloatingButton. Caso não deseje uma activity com FloatingButton selecione BlankActivity. A BlankActivity vem vazia apenas com o minimo necessario para usar aquela activity, ou seja o na BlankActivity a IDE adiciona ele no Manifest como activity, cria o Java herdando de AppCompact com metodo onCreate(), cria 2 XML de layout sendo um o activity_layout.xml e o content_layout.xml.

Os 2 XML são criado para facilitar a organização do codigo.O content como nome já diz vai ter o conteudo principal da activity, listas, botões, etc. e no activity layout é inserido objetos "padrões", que toda pagina tem, como o FloatingButton, Toolbar, e content_layout.

Caso deseje criar uma activity sem FloatingButton selecione BlankActivity, caso selecione a Empity aIDE entende que você vai precisar do FloatingButton e adiciona no XML e já cria o codigo Java para manipula-lo.

A mesma ideia serve para as outras Activity, por exemplo se deseja trabalhar com Mapas selecione a o template com mapa, pois a IDE vai preparar tudo que você precisa para manipular o mapa.